# Does AUSampler support reverb implementation with a SoundFont file?

Tags: ios, core-audio, soundfont

I have successfully loaded SoundFont (.sf2) files in an AUSampler in my IOS app but any programmed reverb is missing. The SF2s contain parameter data for things like pan, envelope and filter cut-off values. These are all preserved apart from the reverb.

Best I can tell, the SF2 format supports 'internal' reverb and chorus units. Are these then missing when loaded in an AUSampler? I can certainly create a new Audio unit in my AUGraph and implement a reverb effect to attempt to achieve something similar but a lot will be lost in translation. For example, I will loose the ability to set individually tailored reverberation amounts on a sample by sample basis within my instrument preset. Instead I will be left with just the ability to route my entire sound bank instrument to a master reverb effect??

Comment: I've tried reverb level on instrument and preset level, but unfortunately I can confirm AUSampler won't play it. I am afraid this requires an additional reverb AU. For the record, the bs-16i app also does not play reverb from the soundfont file, it has its own reverb.